# Running code . in WSL / Command Prompt opens two instances of VS Code

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I'm working with WSL2 with Visual Studio Code by running `code .` in Ubuntu terminal.

I'm creating an application, in the code of this application I'm using winsock2.h header.

The Visual Studio Code showed me a problem:
`Winsock2.h: No such file or directory`

I understand that I am trying to access the Windows libraries through the Linux and it is problematic.

Using ChatGPT as assistant, it gave me a suggestion to run:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-mingw-w64-x86-64
```

to install the Windows development libraries, such as the Windows SDK, on WSL in order to use the Winsock2 library.

**I replaced my Windows username with `<Username>` in my explanation.**

After I ran this command, which didn't help me that much with the previous problem, but now every time I run `code .` From the terminal or from Command Prompt or from Windows Powershell or from Git Bash (I checked in all of these to make sure that the problem is not in Ubuntu-20.04 which I use) so two instances open for me:

1. Opened in the folder of the project I'm working on now, in the side bar it shows me the Git source control related to this project.
2. This instance shows the extra layer of Workspace Trust with checkbox: `Trust the authors of all files in the parent folder 'Users'`,
   above it appears:
   `C:\Users\<Username>`. This instance opened in the root folder, in the side bar it shows me the Git source control related to the previous project I was working on.

But if I run Visual Studio Code by searching for Visual Studio Code after pressing the Win key or I enter directly from the folder: `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\` so only one instance will be opened.

I try to undo it by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge g++-mingw-w64-x86-64
```

But it didn't help.

Running in Command Prompt gave two results:
C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd

I tried to solve it by creating a batch file that launches Visual Studio Code with the "--new-window" or "-n" argument, which forces Visual Studio Code to open in a new window.

I created a code.bat file with the following line: `start "" "C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\Code.exe" --new-window`
and add the location of the "code.bat" file to my system's PATH environment variable.

But it didn't help.

What else can I do to resolve this?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
**I don't know what happened, but this problem suddenly stopped.
I opened a .cpp file with the VS Code, it also opened two instances, this time one was the .cpp file I opened and the other instance was the aforementioned project.
I closed both.
Today when I run code. In the terminal then it brings up only the instance of the project, as it was before this problem.**

Comment: Not quite sure what is happening, but as a first troubleshooting step, try deleting (or renaming, if it makes you feel safer) the `~/.vscode-server` directory in Ubuntu.  It will be regenerated the next time you run `code` in Ubuntu/WSL.

Comment: Glad you got this resolved, even if you don't know how.  I'm recommending (voting) that we close this out since it can't be reproduced and there's no way of knowing what fixed it in order to help future readers.